# Create a stream of custom alternating numbers

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I make an `IntStream` that starts in the middle of a given sequential range, and then streams the next numbers starting in the middle and alternating to the left and right. For example, for a given sequential range of numbers `1 2 3 4 5`, the custom sequence would be `3 2 4 1 5` or `3 4 2 5 1` depending whether you start with left or right first.

I basically am trying to iterate through an array starting from the middle and going outward evenly (not going to the left or right fully first).

I have tried this using just `for` loops but the code is messy and I think it would be **much** better to just line up a collection or stream of numbers instead of checking for it on the fly (because of all the index out of bounds exceptions that have to be checked for). Here is the original code that I think would be much better as a pre computed stream of ints:

```
        int middle = myArray.length / 2;
        Object value = myArray[middle]; //have to reference middle since the for loop won't
        //do operation on value
        for (int offset = 1; true; offset++) {
            int nextRight = middle + offset;
            int nextLeft = middle - offset;
            if (nextRight < myArray.length) { // Have to guard against exception, but can't catch exception ahead of time because left or null may not be empty.
                Object value = myArray[nextRight];
                //do operation on value
            }
            if (nextLeft >= 0) {
                Object value = myArray[nextRight];
                //do operation on value
            }
            if (nextRight >= myArray.length) {
                break; //exit logic
            }
            if (nextLeft < 0) {
                break; //exit logic
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using a for loop but the code is quite messy, let me post it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the way to do this in the stream manner. I mean, you CAN implement an iterator for IntStream, but ,in this case, it would be unreadable for any future uses.

Comment: @zlakad I see. If that is the case, I think pre-computing the list (eg: `3 2 4 1 5`) ahead of time would be much cleaner as I can just iterate through it without checking against all of the potential out of bounds exceptions that can occur by computing it while iterating (like the above code does for example). It would separate out the business logic (eg: "do operation on value") from the messy custom iteration logic.

Comment: It seems to me that you must implement TWO iterators, and combine them into the single one. IDK how...

Comment: I just up-voted your question, b/c it stared to spin my mind.

Comment: @zlakad mine too... :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036210/1059372

Comment: @Eugene well, we like challenges, don't we? :)

Comment: This reads like a *really* hi-spec binary search, but I'm not entirely clear what it is you're trying to accomplish.  Being able to skip values in iteration is one thing, but perhaps there's something else that could be used in place of what many would describe as, "strange, yet curious".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses iterators and streams:

```
boolean toLeft = false;
int size = 5;

int half = size % 2 == 0 ? size / 2 : size / 2 + 1;
IntStream inferiorStream = IntStream.iterate (half, x -> x - 1);
IntStream superiorStream = IntStream.iterate (half, x -> x + 1);

OfInt a = toLeft 
          ? inferiorStream.iterator () 
          : superiorStream.iterator ();
OfInt b = toLeft 
          ? superiorStream.skip (1).iterator () 
          : inferiorStream.skip (1).iterator ();

IntStream stream = Stream.generate (() -> IntStream.concat (
    a.hasNext () ? IntStream.of (a.nextInt ()) : IntStream.empty (),
    b.hasNext () ? IntStream.of (b.nextInt ()) : IntStream.empty ()))
    .flatMapToInt (Function.identity ())
    .limit (size);

stream.forEach (System.out :: println);
```

Output (toLeft = true):

```
3
4
2
5
1
```

Output (toLeft = false):

```
3
2
4
1
5
```

Comment: Beware that `Stream.generate` creates an infinite, *unordered* stream, so not only there is no guaranty that the result will reflect the desired order, there is not even a guaranty that `limit` will pick the desired “first” elements of the infinite source. One practical consequence, this stream will break in parallel execution, even if you add the necessary synchronization.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.signum;

static IntStream altSeq(int n) {
    return IntStream.iterate(2 * (n % 2) - 1, i -> -i - signum(i))
                    .map(i -> i / 2 + (n + 1) / 2)
                    .limit(n);
}
```

For example, `altSeq(5)` produces:

```
[3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
```

and running `altSeq(6)` produces:

```
[3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6]
```

Briefly, we generate an ascending sequence that alternates sign:

```
1, -2, 3, -4, 5, ...
```

That's what the `i -> -i - signum(i)` expression does. Then, we divide by two in order to get the offsets from the midpoint:

```
0, -1, 1, -2, 2, ...
```

That's where the `i / 2` in the first term of the `map` expression comes from. Then we add the midpoint of the range 1..n which is `(n + 1) / 2`, the second term of the `map` expression. For n = 5, this gives us

```
3, 2, 4, 1, 5, ...
```

Starting at 1 works for odd length sequences. For even lengths, we want to start with -1. The seed expression `2 * (n % 2) - 1` computes the right seed value for both even and odd length sequences.

Finally, we apply `limit(n)` to terminate the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can think of this, don't know if it fits your requirements though:

```
public static IntStream generate(int[] x, boolean direction) {
    int length = x.length / 2;

    IntStream right = IntStream.range(1, length + 1)
            .mapToObj(i -> {
                return direction ? new Integer[] { i, -1 * i } : new Integer[] { -1 * i, i };
            })
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .mapToInt(i -> x[length + i]);

    return IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(x[length]), right);
}
```

Comment: Could have been replaced with this ? https://pastebin.com/JZ7QeKeY , toLeft is initialized to false and it's never changed.

Comment: @zlakad it's not that difficult actually, if you consider the middle to be `zero` then you are moving `-1, 1` and then `-2, 2` and so on...

Comment: @Holger *simpler*... it took me quite a while to understand what the hell is going on in those simpler approaches :)

Comment: There are different types of simplicity. By the way, your code seems to have problems with even array lengths; that’s why my answer uses `int mid = (n-1)/2;`. Further, you could use `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`; you only have to change the subsequent steps to `flatMapToInt(…).map(…)`. Or fuse the `mapToObj` and subsequent `flatMapToInt` to a single `.flatMap(direction? i -> IntStream.of(i, -i): i -> IntStream.of(-i, i))`. Then, you could use `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, length)` and have a solution that can compete with mine or Stuart Marks’ regarding simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said, you want to use the sequence to iterate over an array, I changed it to produce numbers including zero, but excluding *n*, so you can directly pass in an array length and get valid indices.

Then you can use

```
static IntStream altSeq(int n) {
    int mid = (n-1)/2;
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
                    .map(i -> mid + (i>>>1)*signum(rotateRight(i,1)));
}
```

The approach is similar to [Stuart Marks’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48048629/2711488), but uses an `IntStream.rangeClosed()` as base, which creates a *sized* stream, which works much more efficient than creating an infinite stream (like `iterate`) and applying a `limit`, especially for operations like `toArray`, `count`, and for `parallel` streams. In other words, the performance is on par with iterating over the range/array in the usual order.

The natural number range is converted by using the lowest bit as sign, which is alternating for ascending numbers, and shifting the numbers one bit to the right, which is equivalent to dividing the magnitude of the numbers by two.

An alternative notation performing only one bitshift per element would be

```
static IntStream altSeq(int n) {
    int mid = (n-1)/2;
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
                    .map(i -> Integer.rotateRight(i, 1))
                    .map(i -> mid + (i&Integer.MAX_VALUE)*signum(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we can customise the `IntStream.generate` method to generate the `IntStream` in the sequence we need

```
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    final int[] arr = IntStream.range(0, 9).toArray(); //test data
    int mid = arr.length / 2;
    SeqGen seq = new SeqGen(arr, mid);
    List<Integer> ints = IntStream.generate(() -> seq.gen())
            .limit(arr.length)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(ints);
}
```

SeqGen

```
private class SeqGen {
    int[] arr;
    int start;
    int curr;
    boolean flag;

    public SeqGen(int[] arr, int start) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.start = start;
    }

    public int gen() {
        int ret = -1;
        int l = arr[start + curr];
        int r = arr[arr.length - curr - start - 1];
        if (!flag) {
            ret = l;
            curr++;
        } else {
            ret = r;
        }
        flag = !flag;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

output

```
[4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0, 8]
```

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035481/create-a-stream-of-custom-alternating-numbers#comment83111662_48037018) applies here too: `Stream.generate` creates an infinite, *unordered* stream, so this happens to work with the current implementation in a sequential context, but is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

As you are willing to consider a collection, the following "low tech" approach is quite straightforward:

```
public static List<Integer> f(int len) {
    int offset = len / 2;

    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>(len);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < len; i++) {
        int index = offset + i * direction(i);
        indices.add(index);
        offset = index;
    }

    return indices;
}


private static int direction(int size) {
    return (size & 1) == 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

The call to `f(5),` returns: `[2, 1, 3, 0, 4]`

The direction ( left to right or right to left ) can be be modified by changing `direction()`. If you really need 1-based indices, modify `f()` to have: `indices.add(index+1)`

Answer (score 1):

Used formula to generate stream for any sequential range from start to end

```
public static IntStream shuffle(int start, int end){
    int size = end - start + 1;
    int center = start + ((size + 1) >> 1) - 1;
    int even = (size + 1) & 1;
    int direction = 1 - (even << 1); //for left first: (even << 1) - 1;
    return IntStream.range(1, size + 1)
            .map(i -> center + (even + i * direction * ((((i + 1) & 1) << 1) - 1)) / 2);
}
```